Definition of Composition of Binary Relations
The following is the definition of the composition of relations taken from Wikipedia:

Why don't we, with the aim of being more general in our defintion, define it as follows:
If R is a relation from X to Y,  S is a relation from J to Z, then their composition R;S is the relation
R;S = set( (x,z) in X x Z : there exists b in intersection(Y,J) such that (x,b) belongs to R and (b,z) belong to S)
The reason I believe it is more general is because using "my" defintion the composition of two relations can be defined for ANY two relations. However, if we were to consider the Wikipedia definition, then if I were to ask you to find the composition between a relation R defined in NxN and a relation S defined in RxN then you would not be able to give me an answer, since the definition only talks about the composition of functions of the form R in X x Y and S in Y x Z.

So just replace $Y$ with $Y \cap J$? I mean, I guess you could, but this doesn't seem like it's more general.

Please don't use images of math and text.  Instead, transcribe them using Mathjax.  Please use Mathjax for the text you write.

A very good reason for using the standard definition is that it makes sets and relations into a category, and categories pervade all of mathematics. Another (related) reason is that taking intersections really only makes sense in material set theory, but relations can be formalised in more structural foundations like type theory where you can't talk about the intersection of two types.

Intersections of arbitrary sets make no sense in ordinary mathematics. They need to be a subset of some common set.

@Trebor I had no idea of this. Why is that so?

Intersections of arbitrary sets make perfect sense. $$A\cap B:={x\in A\mid x\in B}=B\cap A$$ is a subset of both $A$ and $B$. No 'ambient set' is needed.

Does this answer your question? When can composition be applied to two relations/functions? Exercise 4.2.15 - How to prove it See also Composition of relations and function composition with different domain and codomain.

Definitions are a matter of social convention and are at least a little bit arbitrary.   Sometimes there are objective reasons why a particular choice of definition is better.  Often they are just a convention: the specific choice doesn't matter too much, what matters is that everyone agrees on a common meaning for the term.
In this case, it arguably doesn't make much of a difference either way.  The standard definition has some advantages: for example, the condition for when relations can be composed is similar to the condition for when functions can be composed.
I suggest you not worry about it too much and "go with the flow" on this one.
